# Can a complementizer (C) take two complements (COMPS)?

Tags: syntax, english, syntax-trees, conjunctions, complement

The 1997 paper "[English Relative Clause Constructions](https://scholar.archive.org/work/2ribfrylbvchhb6543sbeqall4/access/wayback/http://lingo.stanford.edu/sag/papers/rel-pap.pdf)" by Ivan A. Sag has these diagrams:
[image]

(53) shows a diagram of *to go to the UK*, and (54) of *for them to go to the UK*. In (54), complementizer (C) *for* is shown to take two complements (COMPS): an NP (*them*) and a CP (*to go to the UK*).

In generative grammar, is it possible for a comlementizer to have two complements as above? Or is it something that is allowed only in HPSG?

Comment: I would say *them* goes in the specifier of the infinitival clause, an analysis without two complements.

Comment: @Keelan You mean _them_ as the subject of the infinitival clause? But that's not Sag's approach in the paper, where he specifically says that _them to go to the UK_ isn't a constituent.

Comment: I haven't read the paper and don't know HPSG, but indeed, I would differ from Sag on this from the perspective of more traditional generative grammar. The possibility of conjunction (*I want for [them to go] and [him to come]*) suggests that *them to go ...* is a constituent.

Comment: @Keelan The paper shows examples (57)-(60) on pages 28-29 to  present arguments against NP+CP forming a constituent. Specifically, (57) rebuts your 'possibility of conjunction' argument. That said, how to analyze this construction is not an issue here. How a complementizer can have an NP and a CP as complements is.

Comment: Yes, such tests are only indications and you should always use more than one.

Answer (score 2):

Later generative grammar usually insists on binary branching, so, as Keelan already said in a comment, you get *C:for + IP:[them to go to the UK].* Then, you need a rule of *exceptional case marking*, in which C can assign case to the specifier of its complement phrase ("them" has objective case, which can only depend on "for"). Maybe the selection of a clausal complement plus case government of a constituent different from that is what prompts this analysis with two complements. You might then state a predication relation between the two complements separately, in order to emulate the existence of a full clause.

I don't knwo what exactly HPSG says here. GG would not use this structure, it treats "for" as a complementiser of one single clause. I don't know what sense of "C" is assumed above such that a "C" element could have an NP argument. The above analysis already treats infinitival "to" as a C, and that's also problematic. So I would conclude that "C" already has a different meaning in HPSG

Comment: The paper says C stands for complementizer, so I don't think C has a different meaning in this paper or HPSG in general. I gather you're not aware of C taking two complements like this. So I'm not the only one who thinks this is strange.

Comment: Yes, but I meant that the notion of "complementiser" itself seems to be different...

Comment: That's possible, but since HPSG is a type of phrase structure grammar, I don't think they would use the same terminology differently in a confusing way.